# btrfs: mounting a subvolume in a different path does not work - No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, btrfs

I want to mount the subvolume in a different directory on the @ subvolume... should be possible or did I miss something?

```
# btrfs subvolume create /foo 
# mkdir -p /mnt/storage1/foo 
# mount -t btrfs -o subvol=foo /dev/sda2 /mnt/storage1/foo 
mount: No such file or directory
```

I'm running stock Ubuntu 14.04.2

```
# btrfs subvol list /
ID 257 gen 1489 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 1473 top level 5 path @home
ID 2784 gen 1474 top level 257 path foo
```

`fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2 /     btrfs  defaults,subvol=@ 0 1
/dev/sda2 /home btrfs  defaults,subvol=@home 0 0
# that's not working 
/dev/sda2 /mnt/storage/foo btrfs defaults,subvol=foo 0 0
```

Edit: Looks like a bug - this works:

```
mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=2786 /dev/sda2 /mnt/storage1/foo
```

Maybe it's related to this? http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.btrfs/29167

Comment: I have the same problem. I could not find any existing bugs on this, so I opened one here: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs/+bug/1445283](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs/+bug/1445283)

Comment: Works for me on Btrfs v3.17. Your fstab config came in handy :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you did `btrfs subvolume create /foo`, then presumably the subvolume is actually located at `@/foo` in the filesystem (since subvolume `@` is usually mounted at `/` by convention). So your mount should instead be:

```
mount -t btrfs -o subvol=@/foo /dev/sda2 /mnt/storage1/foo
```

And you fstab should read:

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/storage1/foo btrfs defaults,subvol=@/foo 0 0
```

The [btrfs Wiki has more info about subvolume layout](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Layout), which might be helpful for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your path in fstab is `/mnt/storage/foo` when it should be `/mnt/storage1/foo`

Comment: It was a spelling mistake, fixed that.